# Swift Constraints & Anchors

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

In fact, I was looking for an example of a drop-down button. But unfortunately it turned out to be not fully working, and I do not know well how dynamic constraints and anchors work. Therefore I ask for your help.

> 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with
>   anchors  and
>    because they have no
>   common ancestor. Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in
>   different view hierarchies? That's illegal.

You can find my source code on Github: https://github.com/Archetapp/Drop-Down-Menu/blob/master/sdafjkbslib/ViewController.swift

I found similar problems and their solution was:

- Check whether you added the programmatically created view to its parent before activating constraints.
- Check whether you write constraints activation code inside viewDidLoad () / viewWillAppear (). You should write constraints in the updateViewConstraints or viewWillLayoutSubviews.
- Check whether you turn off translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints.

But it did not help me.

Comment: you need to display dropdown menu right?

Comment: @GaneshManickam yes, forgot to write, it is displayed and working, the problem occurs when the controller is closed (when the button is called by the method RemoveFromSuperview)

Answer (score 1):

For dropdown i mostly prefer this [library](https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown) less number of code and easy to handle

**initialize**

```
let dropDown = DropDown()

// The view to which the drop down will appear on
dropDown.anchorView = view // UIView or UIBarButtonItem

// The list of items to display. Can be changed dynamically
dropDown.dataSource = ["Car", "Motorcycle", "Truck"]
```

**Handle selection**

```
// Action triggered on selection
dropDown.selectionAction = { [unowned self] (index: Int, item: String) in
  print("Selected item: \(item) at index: \(index)")
}
```

**Handle show and hide**

```
dropDown.show()
dropDown.hide()
```

very easy to customize

Hope this will help you